# Django test runner not finding tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am new to both Python and Django and I'm learning by creating a diet management site but I've been completely defeated by getting my unit tests to run.  All the docs and blogs I've found say that as long as it's discoverable from tests.py, tests.py is in the same folder as models.py and your test class subclasses TestCase, it should all get picked up automatically.  This isn't working for me, when I run `manage.py test <myapp>` it doesn't find any tests.

I started with all my tests in their own package but have simplified it down to all tests just being in my tests.py file.  The current tests.py looks like:

```
import unittest
from pyDietTracker.models import Weight
from pyDietTracker.weight.DisplayDataAdapters import DisplayWeight

class TestDisplayWeight(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def testGetWeightInStone_KG_Correctly_Converted(self):
        weight = Weight()
        weight.weight = 99.8

        testAdapter = DisplayWeight(weight)
        self.assertEquals(testAdapter.GetWeightInStone(), '15 st 10 lb')
```

I have tried it by subclassing the Django TestCase class as well but this didn't work either.  I'm using Django 1.1.1, Python 2.6 and I'm running Snow Leopard.

I'm sure I am missing something very basic and obvious but I just can't work out what. Any ideas?

Edit:  Just a quick update after a comment

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.admin',
'pyDietTracker',
 )
```

To get the tests to run I am running `manage.py test pyDietTracker`

Comment: What command are you running to get these to execute?  What's your `settings` look like?  Is this application in the list of INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: I've updated the question with my INSTALLED_APPS, is there another part of settings that is relevant? Thanks

Comment: What messages are you actually getting?

Comment: I don't get an error message it just says 0 tests run. I'm away from the computer atm but when I try to name the test class directly I get an error along the lines of not a suitable test case. I will post it up exactly when I get back.

Comment: @L2Type: You can't easily name the TestCase class directly.  You name the app, the Django runner does it's discovery thing by looking in models.py and tests.py

Comment: My tests run fine in my source tree, but in my distribution tree where all files are .pyc, I get `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s` even though the tests.pyc files are there.  Is there a way to discover .pyc files? Using `--pattern *.pyc` didn't work. If this is a known limitation, that's fine but I'd like to see that in the docs.

Comment: you should use `django TestCase` class
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Worked it out.

It turns out I had done `django-admin.py startproject pyDietTracker` but not `python manage.py startapp myApp`.  After going back and doing this, it did work as documented.  It would appear I have a lot to learn about reading and the difference between a site and an app in Django.

Thank you for your help S.Lott and Emil Stenström.  I wish I could accept both your answers because they are both helped alot.

Most important lesson **Tests only work at the app level not the site level**

Answer (score 240):

I had the same issue but my root cause was different.

I was getting `Ran 0 tests`, as OP.

But it turns out the **test methods inside your test class must start with keyword `test` to run**.

Example:

```
from django.test import TestCase


class FooTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def this_wont_run(self):
        print 'Fail'

    def test_this_will(self):
        print 'Win'
```

#### Also the files with your TestCases in them have to start with `test`.

Comment: if it still does not work, check if the filename matches this pattern: `test*.py` This is how django picks the test suit files. [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests)

Comment: For other readers, there is also a change to use Django's TestCase instead of unittest.TestCase

Answer (score 157):

If you're using a `yourapp/tests` package/style for unittests, make sure there's a `__init__.py` in your `tests` folder (since that's what makes it a Python module!).

Comment: Yes! If you use a custom folder for the desired app to run tests (e.g: `my_apps/app_name/`", then you should create `__init__.py` file in `my_apps/`.

Comment: For me, when I add the `__init__.py` file in each level of subfolders `my_app/tests/app/models` tests was found.

Answer (score 52):

I can run test for specific apps e.g.

```
python project/manage.py test app_name
```

but when I run

```
python project/manage.py test
```

0 tests was found

Figure out I need to run this in the same directory as manage.py

so the solution would be, cd to project directory and run

```
python manage.py test
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me (https://github.com/agconti/cookiecutter-django-rest/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.github_repository_name%7D%7D/fabfile.py)

Comment: This helped me, thanks. It appears that test runner discovers current working directory, which must itself be a Python package (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests). Alternatively, you can invoke tests like this `python project/manage.py test project/`

Comment: Really simple solution, but I if you now a workaround to user `python src/manage.py test` and run all tests please share and update the aswer. Thanks a lot the solution worked for me.

Comment: "cd to project directory and run" - thanks !

Answer (score 28):

In my case, the app folder itself was missing an `__init__.py`. This results in the behaviour that the test will be run with `python manage.py test project.app_name` but not with `python manage.py test`.

```
project/
  app_name/
    __init__.py   # this was missing
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me find my problem which was that I created a folder 'tests' to hold my test scripts, but forgot to add the file __init__.py

Comment: Same thing here: I had `project/apps/core`, with no `__init__.py` in `project/apps`.

Comment: Thanks for posting this - I created a `tests` subfolder but forgot to include an `__init__.py` underneath that direction. Adding it did the trick!

Comment: Thanks. Struggled with this problem for very long. Finally adding `__init__.py` to app worked. Initially I was just checking `__init__.py` in the tests folder.

Answer (score 20):

This may also happen when you are using a `tests` module instead of a `tests.py`. In this case you need to import all the test classes into the `__init__.py` of your tests module, e.g.

```
tests/
    __init__.py
    somemodule.py
```

In your `__init__.py` you now need to import the `somemodule` like this:

```
from .somemodule import *
```

Comment: this was my problem and fixed it thanks to you. regards!

Comment: This may work but I don't think it's the right fix as I have another python project that does not require this import to run tests.

Comment: That was also my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am using scripts to run my tests. A few months and a new computer later, tests unexpectedly broke. This fixed it. No idea what the difference was. Maybe a different python version. Maybe a newer Django...

Answer (score 18):

In my case, I typed `def` instead of `class`. Instead of

```
class TestDisplayWeight(TestCase): # correct!
```

I had

```
def TestDisplayWeight(TestCase): # wrong!
```

Answer (score 16):

This also happens if you have a syntax error in your tests.py.

Answer (score 9):

I know I am late at this point but I also had trouble with

```
Found 0 test(s).
System check identified no issues (1 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I have followed all the steps still I was facing the same issue. My fix was I missed `__init__.py` file in the test directory. Adding the file and re-running the command solved my issue.

**HIGHLIGHTING IT A BIT:**

**Make sure you have `__init__.py` file**

Comment: This fixed my issue (y)

Answer (score 7):

in my case, I miss starting my functions name with **test_** 
and when run my test with :

```
python manage.py test myapp
```

result was :

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

it seems Django cannot recognize my tests!

then i change **myproject/myapp/test.py** file like this :

```
from django.test import TestCase
# Create your tests here.
class apitest(TestCase):

    def test_email(self):
        pass
    def test_secend(self):
        pass
```

after that result is:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 2.048s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another one that I've just had: Check your test files are not executable. My virtualbox auto-mounted them as executable so the test discover missed them completely. I had to add them into the relevant `__init__.py` files before someone told me what the issue was as a work around, but now they are removed, and non-executable and everything _just_works.

Comment: When running tests inside a docker image on Docker Desktop, I was having the same problem. The solution came from this answer. I had lots of test_*.py inside /{app}/tests/ folders. When importing this tests in /{app}/tests/__init__.py solved.
Thanks a lot for that insight.

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen when I had a test.py file, and a test/ subdirectory, in the same Django app directory.  I guess I'm confusing python or the test runner whether I'm looking for a test module (in test.py) or a test package (in test/ subdir).

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/

The most common reason for tests not running is that your settings aren't right, and your module is not in INSTALLED_APPS.

We use `django.test.TestCase` instead of `unittest.TestCase`.  It has the `Client` bundled in.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase

Comment: Thanks, I've been over page and my module is in the INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: **test methods inside your test class must start with keyword test to run.**

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run a test in your main app, such as my_app/my_app/ make sure you have the following checked:

1. App name is listed in INSTALLED_APPS inside `settings.py`
2. Make sure your `DATABASES['default']` inside `settings.py` is set properly
3. The App has a `models.py` (even if you are not using one, at least an empty one is required to be there)

Comment: If you use a ''tests'' folder, remember to put a ''_ _init_ _.py'' file there.

Answer (score 1):

Using this syntax

```
python manage.py test
```

instead of `./manage.py test` solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter this error after upgrading to Django 3, it might be because the `-k` parameter changed meaning from:

```
-k, --keepdb          Preserves the test DB between runs.
```

to

```
-k TEST_NAME_PATTERNS   Only run test methods and classes that match the pattern or substring. Can be used multiple times. Same as unittest -k option.
```

So just replace `-k` with `--keepdb` to make it work again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, turns out I saved the `__init__` as a python file but it did not put `.py` at the end of its name. I added `.py` at the end of file's name. it was ok afterwards

(in other words, I had created `__init__` instead of `__init__.py` )

Answer (score 1):

I had to `cd` into the Django project directory for the tests to be found.

Answer (score 0):

In the same file, I had two test classes with the **SAME NAME**, and of course this prevented all tests from running.

Answer (score 0):

I created a method called `run` in my test class which turned out to be a very bad idea. Python could see that I wanted to run tests, but was unable to. This problem is slightly different, but the result is the same - it made it seem as if the tests couldn't be found.

Note that the following message was displayed:

`You want to run the existing test: <unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=0 errors=0 failures=0>`

Answer (score 0):

Run `--help` and look for verbose. Crank it to max.

I ran `manage.py test --verbose` and found this debug output right at the top:

`>nosetests --with-spec --spec-color --verbose --verbosity=2`.

Oh look! I had installed and forgotten about `nosetests`. And it says `--verbosity=2`. I figured out that 3 is the max and running it with 3 I found lots of these:

```
nose.selector: INFO: /media/sf_C_DRIVE/Users/me/git/django/app/tests/test_processors.py is executable; skipped
```

That gave me the right hint. It indeed has problems with files having the x-bit set. However, I was thrown off the track as it had run SOME of the tests - even though it explicitly said it would skip them. Changing bits is not possible, as I run the tests in a VM, sharing my Windows NTFS-disk. So adding `--exe` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and it was because my filename had a `-` char in its name. 
My filename was `route-tests.py` and changed it to `route_tests.py`

Answer (score 0):

Django engine searches files and folders with `test_` prefix (inside of a `tests` folder). In my case it was simple solution.

So, be sure to checkout file/folder name starts with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was caused by **init**.py at the project root - deleted that, all tests ran fine again.

Answer (score 0):

This is late. but you can simply add your app name in front of importing models. like

```
    from myapp.models import something
```

This works for Me.

Answer (score 0):

In Django, methods in test classes must start with "test" keyword. for example test_is_true(). methods name like is_true() will not execute.

Comment: Suggestion has already been answered here  => https://stackoverflow.com/a/53769987/5472004

Answer (score 0):

In my i resolve this, using python manage.py test apps and works, because i'm creating my apps inside folder apps, not at the same level of project.

```
    .
    ├── HFarm
    ├── .vscode
    ├── apps/
    │   └── accounts/
    │       ├── migrations
    │       ├── templates
    │       ├── tests/
    │       │   ├── __init__.py
    │       │   └── testAccount.py
    │       ├── utils/
    │       │   ├── __init__.py
    │       │   └── mail.py
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── admin.py
    │       ├── apps.py
    │       ├── forms.py
    │       ├── models.py
    │       ├── urls.py
    │       └── views.py
    ├── backend/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    └── manage.py
```

#tests/**init**.py

```
    from .testsAccount import *
```