# Test not found in github actions

Tags: django, ubuntu, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to do an automated test.
There should be 21 tests, but github-actions can't find them for some reason.
https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/4215160033/jobs/7316095166#step:3:6
[image]

manage.py is under mysite directory, so...
(Below is when I run it on my local PC)

```
(venv) PS D:\OneDrive\dev\portfolio\mysite> python manage.py test
  Found 21 test(s).
  Creating test database for alias 'default'...
  System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
   :
  self.client.post(reverse('vnm:likes', kwargs={'user_id': 1, 'article_id': 99}), follow=True)
  AssertionError: ObjectDoesNotExist not raised

  ======================================================================
  FAIL: test_post_click_good_button 
  (vietnam_research.tests.test_views.TestView)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------

  OK
```

Anyone know a solution?
thanks

Comment: In your workflow (https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/4215160033/workflow), you're not activating `venv` but locally you are.

Comment: thank you. Certainly "venv activate" was none.
next research at 'activate'.
It is difficult because the directory structure is different from the usual environment


```
    - name: Install venv
      run: |
        apt -y install python3.8-venv
        python3 -m venv venv
        venv/bin/activate
        ls
```

Comment: You need to add `sudo` before `apt` here: https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/4216771566/workflow#L30. Also, you need to move this step before your `pip install -r requirements.txt` step to make it install deps under `venv`.

Comment: Azeem san
Thank you for taking the consultation. I want to solve this.
https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/4221902706/jobs/7329752733#step:4:29

If you don't have python3.8-venv, you'll get an error, but in my production environment, the installation of venv seems to work as follows (I'm sorry that it's hard to see because you can't do line breaks)


```
ubuntu@ik1-336-28225:~$ sudo apt -y install python3.8-venv 
 :
python3.8-venv is already the newest version (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.6).  
```

Comment: Error: Process completed with exit code 100.
still seems to be a permission error

Comment: Please test [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJyFUM1uwyAMvucp/AIkh95yqrRe+gzTNDmJldCBYdhEi7SHH9Bqh0rTLiD7+wVGTyNcbshrgJdr1wUeO4CYZas3wJSQ541khFePopTeGuzce6LPTKJ/0rpbmKSiU7ZuudNSZjElAvKUWbNxqMWiQUUU5c4ykKVa4aw2sAzFeP4IWc/76YFzq31lUXQOLhSJF+LZkgDyUmOgGkujt9gRvh9DqX/oFvgExsNOvLfjF+zbOEyWh5q/l4ZPwqqLNoJ9xBuT45pwobr9j5ug/ptN5IlVev3SZ4U/xCoNHhlX6uPRXvIDPvKE6Q==) minimal workflow for your use case.

Comment: the build is [correct](https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/4223129557/jobs/7332485465)! :) But I can only find 0 tests   ... I am reading the log now

Comment: I never knew there was a playground in "Actions" :)

Comment: That's an online linter, not a playground. You removed `.` from here: https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/4223129557/workflow#L27.

Comment: I added '.' but still Found 0 test(s).   I wonder what the other reason is...
[this](https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/4223305832/jobs/7332884769)

Comment: Are you using pytest for writing tests?

Comment: Tests are standard django, run via manage.py
 [test source is here](https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/tree/master/mysite/vietnam_research/tests)

Comment: Azeem san.  I'm sleepy. today is over. thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this [workflow](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/4225152618/workflow#L14-L30) and its respective [run](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/4225152618/jobs/7337044606#step:4:326). Apparently, you did not check out the `__init__.py` files and they are added in your [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/blob/master/.gitignore#L7). So, you need to check those out to make this work. Also, an additional step i.e. `cd mysite` before running the test command. For DB-based tests, you need to provide the env vars also e.g. via GHA secrets.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Looks like it recognized the test thanks to you. [this](https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/4231028109/jobs/7349044338#step:4:831) . Various errors started to appear, but I think it's probably because the migration has not been completed.

Comment: I think there was a "solve" button, but I can't find it. .

Comment: You're welcome! I have posted an answer will the relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your repo (https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio) and testing it locally on my side, I found out that `__init__.py` was missing. Maybe, it was due to the fact that it was added in your [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/blob/master/.gitignore#L7) file which prevented its inclusion in your repo.

Here's the sample workflow that I tested it with:

```yaml
name: python_test

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: duri0214/portfolio

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
        cache: pip

    - name: Set up and run tests
      run: |
        python3 --version
        python3 -m venv venv
        . venv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
        cd mysite
        touch ./vietnam_research/__init__.py
        touch ./vietnam_research/tests/__init__.py
        python manage.py test
```

You may observe the `__init__.py` being manually created in the last step.

So, you have to remove `__init__.py` from your `.gitignore` file and push those to your repo.

Apart from that, you need to `cd mysite` first before running the test command. Also, your tests seem to be using database and environment variables to be run successfully. So, you'll have to configure the database (if required) and set the env vars via GitHub secrets accordingly.

Comment: Azeem san. thanks a lot :)
I also understood the importance of `__init__`, which I had previously ruled out as meaningless.

Comment: @yoshitakaokada: You're welcome! :) You might want to go through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037364/django-test-runner-not-finding-tests). Might be helpful.