# Django Test - Not working in GitHub actions

Tags: django, testing, github-actions

I have 2 Django tests that are working perfectly fine locally but it fails on GitHub actions. Python version 3.9

- Requirements.txt

```
Django==4.1.7
django-crum==0.7.9
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.12
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
flake8==5.0.4
openpyxl==3.0.10
pandas==1.5.1
Pillow==9.3.0
python-dotenv==0.19.0
XlsxWriter==1.1.5
xmltodict==0.13.0
```

This is the code:

- Models

```py
class Empresa(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name='Razon Social')
    cuit = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[MinLengthValidator(11)])
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        if not self.user:
            user = get_current_user()
            if user and not user.pk:
                user = None
            if not self.pk:
                self.user = user
            self.user = user
        return super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        return item
```

And I try to test:

1. Creation successfully of Empresa -> It works ok
2. Error on creation because of a long name -> It works locally but not on GitHub actions
3. Error on creation because of a long cuit-> It works locally but not on GitHub actions

This is the test:

```py
class EmpresaTesting(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

        self.user = User.objects.create(username='testuser', password='12345')
        self.user.save()

    def test_create_empresa_ok(self):
        this_empresa = Empresa.objects.create(name='Empresa 1', cuit='30999999991', user=self.user)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(this_empresa, Empresa))
        self.assertEqual(str(this_empresa), 'Empresa 1')

    def test_create_empresa_long_name(self):
        long_name = "a" * 121
        with self.assertRaisesMessage(DataError, "Data too long for column 'name' at row 1"):
            Empresa.objects.create(name=long_name, cuit='30999999991', user=self.user)

    def test_create_empresa_long_cuit(self):
        with self.assertRaisesMessage(DataError, "Data too long for column 'cuit' at row 1"):
            Empresa.objects.create(name="Empresa 1", cuit='123456789012', user=self.user)
```

And this is the error I receive in GitHub actions

```
FAIL: test_create_empresa_long_cuit (export_lsd.tests.EmpresaTesting)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/el_conta/el_conta/export_lsd/tests.py", line 28, in test_create_empresa_long_cuit
    Empresa.objects.create(name="Empresa 1", cuit='123456789012', user=self.user)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 126, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 876, in _assert_raises_or_warns_cm
    yield cm
AssertionError: DataError not raised

======================================================================
FAIL: test_create_empresa_long_name (export_lsd.tests.EmpresaTesting)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/el_conta/el_conta/export_lsd/tests.py", line 24, in test_create_empresa_long_name
    Empresa.objects.create(name=long_name, cuit='30999999991', user=self.user)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 126, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 876, in _assert_raises_or_warns_cm
    yield cm
AssertionError: DataError not raised
```

- GitHub Actions workflow

```
name: Django CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "develop" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "develop" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.8, 3.9]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        
    - name: Check pending migrations
      run: |
        python manage.py makemigrations --check --dry-run
        python manage.py migrate
    
    - name: Lint with Flake8
      run: |
        flake8 --count --show-source --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=130 --statistics --ignore=C901,F811
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        python manage.py test
```

Comment: Please include your GHA workflow in your question along with your `requirements.txt` file and Python version.

Comment: Ready, I've update it. Thanks

Comment: GHA workflow is still missing.

Comment: Ready, sorry!!!

Comment: Thanks! You might want to use [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to contain this as there might be other dependencies amongst the [preinstalled](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md) ones on the runner.

Comment: Here's an example with a similar flow using `venv`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75518724/7670262

Comment: I got the same problem with venv :(

Comment: Please update your workflow accordingly which is not working.

Comment: It seems it's related to DB, I use MySQL locally and GHA sqlite. :)

Comment: Right. So, it's fixed now? You didn't test it locally with SQLite?

Comment: I was testing it with MySQL, I'm working locally with SQLite and it doesn't raise error, that's what I'm solving now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by adding custom validators in the save() method in models, it looks like SQLite doesn't catch DataError. I actually proved that in the shell and I was able to add a 121 characters name.